# Finding the intersection of 2 line given the axis on the Ox coordination

Tags: python, coordinates, intersection

I was given 2 coordination on the Ox line (which means only the straight line, not diagonal), find the integers coordination between these 2 lines.

```
from math import floor
from math import ceil
S = [eval(v) for v in input().split()]
P = [eval(v) for v in input().split()]
a = S[0]
b = S[1]
c = P[0]
d = P[1]
if a>=c and a<d and b>d:
    print(floor(d) - ceil(a))
elif a>=d and a<c and b>c:
    print(floor(c) - ceil(a))
elif d>=a and d<b:
    print(floor(b) - ceil(d))
elif d>=b and d<a:
    print(floor(a) - ceil(d))
else:
    print(floor(max(a, b)- ceil(min(a, b))))
```

but the program return the EOFerror, invalid input, I don't know why?

example inputs

```
1.2 4.5
```

(2 coordination x1, x2 of the first line)

```
2.34 5.6789
```

output

```
2
```